# Two concurrent views with one ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I'm getting mixed answers reading through other posts, but say I have one main ViewModel, which handles two related data models

```
public partial class Product
{
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    public int TemplateID { get; set; }
    public virtual Template Template { get; set; }
}

public Template()
{
    this.Products = new ObservableCollection<Product>();
}
public int TemplateID { get; set; }
public string TemplateName { get; set; }
public virtual ObservableCollection<Product> Products { get; set; }
}
```

Currently, have two separate Views and ViewModels, one that shows all data "byTemplates" and another that shows all the data "byProducts". Both allow CRUD operations. In order to get rid of duplicate codes and commands, I want to merge these two views into one.

Would I still require two ViewModels? Can I have both working off the same data instance? (so if I went and inserted something under the "ByTemplates" view, and switch to "ByProducts" before saving to the database, I'd still see all the changes I have?

EDIT:

I'm currently using tabs to faciliate this.
My views are here:

By Product Tab
[image: ByProduct View]

By Templates Tab (user can select a Template, and the "Associated Products" ListView will show all prodcucts linked to "template")
[image: ByTemplate View]

Comment: Could you be more accurate in the description of the views? You mean they have the same structure but don't display the same data? Maybe you could build a `UserControl` able to manage both but hard to say without more informations.

Comment: So I think you can refactor the code of the two VMs in a common base class, say `ProductTemplateViewModel`, and keep 2 VMs, one for each view, as classes inheriting from it. As for the views themselves you can share code by using `UserControl`s but it's often not worth the trouble if you only have a little duplication.

Comment: I guess my concern with keeping it how i have already (2VMs), is sharing the commands, and i'm worried i'm creating too many instances of the database. But your input is appreciated - guess I was doing OK all along ;P

Answer (score 0):

What you are saying is pretty much possible, viewmodel can contain multiple models combined together acting as one parent viewmodel and it is up to view which all properties that it is interested in binding with.
           Having two separate views or not is a design discussion but it is not mandatory. Neither having one viewmodel per model is required. Purpose of having view model is to get rid of direct dependency on a particular business model and merge and mold data according to UI needs. So yes you can do what you intend to do.
            Please share detail xaml and existing model/viewmodel if you want in depth how to do, else you are all set.

Answer (score 0):

I would tend to use a single viewmodel where both views are interconnected. An example being detail and summary view of the same data perhaps.

In the scenario you describe, if both views are leveraging the same data and methods then sure, keep them as one viewmodel. If however you are parametising each command to work on a subset then it sounds as though seperation will be better - I would look to do this by base classing the common elements to improve reuse and maintenance and then extend into specific viewmodels for each subset. That also offers better extensions later.